# React with express server giving me 400 on post

Tags: reactjs, express

Can't figure out why I keep getting a 400 it's driving me mad.

In my express server:

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.body)
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  client.messages
    .create({
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
      to: '13105551212',
      body: req.body.body
    })
    .then(() => {
      res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false }));
    });
});
```

This is in a root directory and I run it on port 5000.  localhost:5000
I'm just trying to check if I even hit the server.

In a sub directory `client` I have a react build folder where I load my front end.
There I run this method:
this.state.method = 'hi this is test';

```
export function twilioSend(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ submitting: true });
  fetch('/api/messages', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.message)
  })
  .then(res => res.text())          // convert to plain text
.then(text => console.log(text))

}
```

In my network tab:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/messages
```

The error I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please create post the sample value for this.state.message, or create a project on https://codepen.io/ which have same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server, send as object:

```
res.send({ success: true });
```

And

```
res.send({ success: false });
```

In your frontend, get as:

```
fetch('/api/messages', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ message: this.state.message })
})
.then(res => res.json())
```